# bundle, rails 3 and dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, dreamhost

I get a

```
Could not find i18n-0.5.0 in any of the sources
```

error when deploying my rails 3 app to a shared dreamhost.

Support suggested installing bundler 0.9.9 which I did but when I run `bundle install` in my apps folder i get the message that Bundle is an unknown command. Apparently Bundler isn't in my path.

The problem is that I'm a complete unix noob and don't know how to add this so that `bundle` is a known command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the path on the command line with

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/where/the/bundle/binary/is
```

To set the path permanently, add the statement above to the `.bashrc` file in your home folder.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamhost accounts don't come with bundler installed, but you can easily install it locally.  Heres a tutorial from the dreamhost wiki: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Bundler .

- If you installed it correctly its probably in the folder `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/`
- you can check by running `gem environment`.
- Under `gem paths` there will be one or more locations. It'll be on one of those.
- type `pico /home/_your_user_name/.bashrc`
- add the line: `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/bundle/gem` .
- save and quit pico (cntrl+x, then answer yes)
- now you have to reload your bashrc file: `source /home/_your_username/.bashrc`
- run: `bundle -v` and if it tells you what version you have you're good to go.

Alternatively you can freeze your gems into your application on your development computer and then upload the project with the gem files in it to your dreamhost account. Heres a tutorial on that: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php?title=Freezing_Gems&oldid=23877

Comment: thanks for the info. With a new account Bundler version 1.0.7 is installed by default. The wiki mentions that you need 0.9.9. Is this still a requirement because RubyGems 1.3.6 is installed